# PyQt4: Move context menu to position

Tags: python, popup, pyqt, contextmenu, move

How would you change the position of a popup menu in pyqt4? This code doesn't seem to do it.

```
    self.popMenu.exec_(self.table.mapToGlobal(point))
    position = self.popMenu.pos()
    self.popMenu.move(position.x() + 100, position.y() + 100)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You version doesn't work because `exec_` opens the menu *synchronously*, i.e. `exec_` will block/wait until menu is closed. So your `move` is processed after the menu is closed.

You can use `popup` instead of `exec_`. That is asynchronous, so the following code will be executed while the menu is open.

Or you can calculate your desired position *before* calling `exec_`.