# How to move (re-position) PyQT menu when it is displayed?

Tags: python, pyqt, position, pyqt5, qmenu

I have a simple app in PyQT5 and Python 3. There is a system tray icon with assigned menu. Whenever tray icon is clicked, context menu should be updated and displayed. The following simple code should do it:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSystemTrayIcon, QMenu, QAction, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import sys

def add_items():
    # add Clear option that clears the menu
    menu.addAction(QAction("Clear "*20, triggered=menu.clear, parent=menu))
    # add QUIT option that exits the app
    menu.addAction(QAction("QUIT", triggered=sys.exit, parent=menu))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)  # create app

# create system tray icon
tray = QSystemTrayIcon(parent=app)
tray.setIcon(QIcon('tray_icon.png'))
tray.show()

# create menu and assign it to tray icon
menu = QMenu(None)
tray.setContextMenu(menu)
# add items ???before??? menu is shown (when tray icon is activated)
menu.aboutToShow.connect(add_items)

sys.exit(app.exec())  # run app
```

However, the menu is not updated BEFORE it is displayed (as signal name 'aboutToShow' suggests). It is updated AFTER displaying. And the problem is - position of menu is adjusted to its original width (not width after update), so every time I click on menu item 'Clear ...' and menu is cleared, the next time it appears, its position is fixed for empty menu and the item 'Clear ...' is only partially visible, because it is much longer than empty menu and disappears somewhere after edge of the screen.
So, I need to move / re-position the menu to be fully visible.

**Question: How can I move the displayed menu?**

I tried move() method and others from [QMenu doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html), but it somehow do not react in this particular situation, it seems like UI of menu is blocked while displayed. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629634/pyqt4-move-context-menu-to-position), but in my case, I think I can not pop-up the menu, because it is displayed by tray icon internally. Any tips really appreciated (even updating menu before showing or any other solutions).

Comment: Try calling `menu.adjustSize()` after re-setting the items.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you for a tip. However, the menu adjusts its size correctly. The problem is it adjusts its size - the menu enlarges over the edge of screen, but does not move, so a part of the menu is not visible. I need to move the menu from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2). And action menu.move(x,y) is not doing anything.

Comment: Well, I found out why the move() does not work - because the menu somehow thinks it is hidden even though it is displayed. Tried to call tray.contextMenu().isHidden() while menu was displayed and 100% visible but it says "True" = hidden. I really don't know why...